# Getting DataList selected item in a text box

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a DataList on my webpage that is populated by `ItemTemplate`. Each `<tr>` in ItemTemplate has a LinkButton with `CommandName=Select`. When the user clicks on the link button, the corresponding text should appear in the TextBox below.

Inside the ItemTemplate, each row also has a label control which I have put up to be able to be able to find the control and typecast.

Inside the properties window, I am not able to locate the `AutoPostBack` property. 
 
What event has to be used in this case? Would the SelectedIndexChanged serve the purpose?

How do I find the corresponding data from this row and assign it to my textbox?

Comment: Could you prvoide your aspx code and c#?

Comment: You may use SelectedIndexChanged or  ItemCommand event of DataList control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
protected void DataList1_ItemCommand(object source, DataListCommandEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.CommandName == "Select")
            {
                ((TextBox)e.Item.FindControl("Textboxname")).Text = ((Label)e.Item.FindControl("LabelName")).Text;
            }
        }
```